# NoClassDefFoundError when specifying user filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-11, spring-security-ldap

We are trying to build a spring application using LDAP for authentication, but once we overwrite the configure method within WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, we get a NoClassDefFoundError.

Our application is written in java11, we are using code-based/annotation-based configuration. We had some problems with the spring embedded LDAP server, so we switched to OpenLDAP. We verified the server using JXplorer.

This is how our current approach looks like:

#### LdapConfig.java

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class LdapTestConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

  @Autowired
  Environment env;

  public LdapContextSource contextSource()
  {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();

    contextSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.url"));
    contextSource.setBase(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.baseDn"));
    contextSource.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.bindDn"));
    contextSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.password"));
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    return contextSource;
  }

  // This is the method, causing my issue
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
  {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("(cn={0})")
        .groupSearchBase("OU=Account Groups,OU=ITS Security")
        .groupSearchFilter("(cn=AD-this-is-a-specific-group)")
        .contextSource(contextSource());
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
  }
}
```

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  ...

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- ldap related dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.193</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is the full exception, we are getting:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/BindAuthenticator
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/BindAuthenticator
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/BindAuthenticator
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/BindAuthenticator
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.createBindAuthenticator(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:217) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.createLdapAuthenticator(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:180) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.build(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:79) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.configure(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:376) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.configure(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:60) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:384) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:330) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:272) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:201) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.configuration.LdapTestConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d1196fe.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7461bda6.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$2(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7461bda6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3dd2b63a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7461bda6.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 49 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51367', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Which dependency did you expect to include that class? Note that `spring-ldap-core` is not security related, only LDAP related, i.e. it contains classes in package `org.springframework.ldap`, not in `org.springframework.security.ldap`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Wow, that really worked. Now back to trying to work with LDAP